# Using max function on count

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to return 1 result, the year (datetime format) with the highest amount of orders and I'm trying to apply `MAX` function on my `COUNT` to get the value. Where have I gone wrong?

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(ODATE, 'YYYY') AS Year
     , MAX(COUNT(*))
FROM ORDERS
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(ODATE, 'YYYY')
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(ODATE, 'YYYY');
```

Comment: @user1166862 check my adapted answer if you're on Oracle12 c or higher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if the `MAX(COUNT(*))` is valid in this context

Instead do an `ORDER` on the `COUNT(*)` and use the `ROWNUM`

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT TO_CHAR(ODATE, 'YYYY') AS Year, count(*) AS cnt
    FROM ORDERS
    GROUP BY TO_CHAR(ODATE, 'YYYY')
    ORDER BY cnt DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

This will ensure that you keep only the row having the highest count:
The nested query is there because `ROWNUM` is assigned by Oracle before the `ORDER` happens

---

Note that on **Oracle 12c** and above you can use the instruction `FETCH FIRST x ROWS`. Well described [here](http://www.oralytics.com/2014/10/something-new-in-12c-fetch-first-x-rows.html).
This allows to do the same without a subquery because the `FETCH` is applied after the `ORDER`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(ODATE, 'YYYY') AS Year, count(*) AS cnt
FROM ORDERS
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(ODATE, 'YYYY')
ORDER BY cnt DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```